# Oracle behave differently in program and sql developer

Tags: java, oracle

I have a spring batch program that checks if the data from the file exist or not in the oracle database. By recommended step from tuning in SQL Developer, I added 2 indexes for the table a and table b. From SQL Developer, without the indexes, it took 0.5sec to load and with indexes only 0.03 sec. However, when running through the program, the query took 0.5 sec to load. I try added hint, using `hash join` and `index hint` but no difference. It seems like the oracle does not pick the indexes. Can you help me with this?

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    pi.PAYMENT_INSTRUCTION_ID,
    cft.CFT_FILE_DETAIL_ID
FROM
    table_a pi
LEFT JOIN 
    table_b cft ON pi.id = cft.tabla_a_id
WHERE 
    pi.internal_trace_number = :traceNumber
    AND cft.payer_account_no like :payerAccountNo
    AND cft.transaction_amount = :amount;
```

Hint

```
SELECT /*+ use_hash */
--     /*+ INDEX(pi IDX$$_0A0F0001) INDEX(cft DX$$_0A0F0002)*/
pi.PAYMENT_INSTRUCTION_ID
     , cft.CFT_FILE_DETAIL_ID
FROM table_a pi
         LEFT JOIN table_b cft
                   ON pi.id = cft.tabla_a_id
WHERE pi.internal_trace_number = :traceNumber
  AND cft.payer_account_no like :payerAccountNo
  AND cft.transaction_amount = :amount;
```

- UPDATE
- queries use for indexes

```
create index TABLE_A_ID on
    TABLE_A (TO_NUMBER("INTERNAL_TRACE_NUMBER"), "CFT_FILE_DETAIL_ID",
"PAYMENT_INSTRUCTION_ID");


create index TABLE_B_ID on
    TABLE_B ("PAYER_ACCOUNT_NO", "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT", "CFT_FILE_DETAIL_ID");


create bitmap index join_pi_cft
    on TABLE_A(CFT_FILE_DETAIL_ID)
    from TABLE_A PI, TABLE_B_ID CFT
        WHERE PI.CFT_FILE_DETAIL_ID = CFT.CFT_FILE_DETAIL_ID;
```

Comment: Have you created indexes on the join keys i.e  table_a.id and table_b.id? You better filter out rows before performing the join operation using the where clause.

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot so instead of 2 indexes, i added one more for join index?

Comment: How are you passing/setting the bind variables, from both SQL Developer and your application; and what data types are the columns and bind variables/values? The `to_number()` in your first index looks wrong, and suggests a data type mismatch; which might prevent the index being used, depending on the value it's trying to compare against (i.e. a string or a number).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create indexes for:

- table_a.internal_trace_number
- table_b.tabla_a_id

After creating these indexes, check the explain plan and the running time of the SQL statement.

Drop your three existing indexes.

Run the following SQL statements:

```
create index table_a_i1 on table_a (internal_trace_number);
create index table_b_i1 on table_b (table_a_id);
```

Comment: I have update the quearies use for indexes. However, all those steps did not have any differences